# Server powerful enough

Tags: dedicated-server

I am planing to buy this dedicated server:

Dual Core ATOM
4GB RAM
1.5TB HDD

Will this be ok to run lets say a php website with about 5.000 unique visitors / day ?

Comment: There is no way we can answer your question without more information, what sort of data is your site serving, is it High Definition media or text files, what will they be doing on your site, how long will they be there. It's like saying, is this car going to be good enough for my needs, it needs to fit 4 people in it.

Answer (score 1):

While the hardware specs of your server are a limiting factor for your applicaiton, you cannot simply use them to calculate a number of visitors. The number of visitors your server will be able to handle will depend on your choice of web server, application coding, database engine, and caching.

In order to determine how many visitors your server could handle you would first need to benchmark your applicaiton in its current environment.

Comment: Lets say that i run a simple wordpress application with 10 000 pageviews/day. Also i will run apache or nginx, mysql5 and php5.3

Comment: 5000 unique visitors a day averages out to about one every 20 seconds, or about one every 10 seconds if it only serves one side of the globe. If it's just a blog site, you'll have no problem.

Comment: Hmmm ... how about a forum ? Lets say vbulletin with about 20 000 pageviews/day ... will the website be laggy ?